# seems like pyodb is installed but gives error saying module is not found python 3.7.5. Jupyter lab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I used pip to install pyodbc.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyodbc
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (4.0.28)
```

But if I simply import pyodbc it gives me an error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: If you run `python -m pip install pyodbc` what happens? `pip` by itself may point to a different interpreter

Comment: You also may want to check `python -m pip -V` and `pip -V` to see if they are the same

Comment: Thanks. This is what I got:
`C:\>python -m pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\>pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

C:\>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version, then roll back to the one before.  My project worked perfectly with 4.0.27 version of this driver, but when I upgraded to 4.0.28 it stopped working (with exactly the same message as you were having)

I reverted back and it now works again.